# Unnecessary hypothesis on ring theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In my algebra course I was given a theorem about rings and morphisms

> Given a ring morphism $f:A \longrightarrow B$ and $I \triangleleft A$ an ideal of $A$ such that $I \supset \ker f$ then $\frac{A}{I}\cong \frac{f(A)}{f(I)}$

Now the proof of this is basically an application of the [first ring isomorphism theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstRingIsomorphismTheorem.html) applied to the map
$$
\mu : f(A) \longrightarrow \frac{f(A)}{f(I)} \\
f(a)\longmapsto f(a)+f(I)
$$
One shows that this is a composition of morphisms and therefore a morphism and the kernel is $I$, so by applying the first ring isomorphism theorem one gets the thesis. However nor the proof given nor the first ring isomorphism theorem require the condition $I \supset \ker f$ so it seems unnecessary to me. Is this true? Also I couldn't find counterexamples or reference for this so even any of that would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof requires that $I\supseteq \ker(f)$, for showing that the "factorization" homomorphism is well-defined.

Comment: If $I=0$ then $A/I\cong A$ but $f(A)/f(I)\cong f(A)$. So obviously some condition is needed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you mean the $\mu$ homomorphism?

Comment: Maybe it is the case that $\ker \mu=I+\ker f$ so to have $\frac{A}{I}$ and not $\frac{A}{I+\ker f}$ we put $I\supset \ker f$

Answer (score 2):

For the universal mapping property we need that $\ker(f)\subseteq I$. This is the following statement:

*Proposition:* Let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of rings and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$ such that $I\subseteq \ker(f)$. Denote by $\pi\colon A\rightarrow A/I$ the canonical projection map. Then there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\overline{f}\colon A/I\rightarrow B$ such that $\overline{f}\circ \pi=f$.

To see that $\overline{f}$ is well-defined, i.e., independent of the representative, we need that $I\subseteq \ker(f)$. Hence, applying this result for the first ring isomorphism theorem, we need also the requirement.

Actually, the example of $I=0$ shows that we also cannot avoid this assumption for the above result. Then $A/I\cong A$ and $f(A)/f(I)\cong f(A)$, so that the claim is $A\cong f(A)$.